# Javascript string concatenation issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a new jQuery variable from some text and another jQuery variable.

This is what I have tried but it just displays "+emc+" instead of the value that the variable is set to.

```
var emc = $(".emc").attr("value");
var new_page = "index.php?emc=+emc+";
```

The new_page variable should display index.php?emc=XXXXXX but instead it displays as index.php?emc=+emc+

Comment: Side note - you're creating a JavaScript variable, not a jQuery variable.

Comment: why is there `jquery-mobile` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I've understood correctly:

```
var new_page = "index.php?emc="+emc;
```

Or, indeed:

```
var new_page = "index.php?emc="+$(".emc").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake in your string concatenation. You wanted to do this:

`var new_page = "index.php?emc="+emc;`

Answer (score 2):

You have included the variable in the constant your code must look like:

```
var emc = $(".emc").attr("value");
var new_page = "index.php?emc="+emc;
```